# Is it necessary to prefix theme_mod, section id and panel id in the customizer?

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

Currently I prefix all of them:

```
$wp_customize->add_panel('themename_panel', $args);

$wp_customize->add_section('themename_section', $args);

$wp_customize->add_setting('themename_setting', $args);
```

But I'm wondering is this necessary?

Comment: yes is necessary add section id visit the link:-https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/

Comment: @AshvinMonpara, thanks for the link, it explains well.

Comment: visti the link give demo:-https://github.com/paulund/Wordpress-Theme-Customizer-Custom-Controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

## Yes.

WordPress is a system that allows for many parts and custom configuration, [`WP_Customize_Manager::add_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_setting/) fits perfectly into that.

But you're not the only one trying to customize this specific WordPress instance, so are all the (activated) plugins and themes. To make sure, you don't overwrite another functionality and your own does not get overridden, prefixes are usually the way to go.

The mentioned function is a perfect example, as all it does do is

```
$this->settings[ $setting->id ] = $setting;
```

Now when Plugin A does

```
$wp_customize->add_panel('panel', $argsA);
```

and theme B has this code

```
$wp_customize->add_panel('panel', $argsB);
```

With which arguments is `panel` created?

---

Of course using prefixes doesn't really solve this problem. So I personally like to use classes and namespaces when possible, to make the chance of collisions even smaller. However, in this case it does not seem possible.

The convention is that you use a prefix that describes you (company name, nickname, ...) as to reduce the risk of someone choosing the same prefix as you

Comment: So a plugin can add sections and panels as well as themes do, right? What about settings? or the option theme_mods_themename, I think it is theme specific, can a plugin add its settings to it?

Comment: Usually any code (plugin, mu-plugin, theme) can do anything, I don't know of any specific restrictions